# fail to create id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am creating dynamic mcq question and now having problem in getting the id of the textbox. i test the id using jquery like below

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter1 = 1;//mcq
var counter = 2;//question
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Q2choice1").click(function (){
    alert ("dsa");
});

$("#addQuestion").click(function () {

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Q'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >' + '</br>' + 
      '<input type="radio" onclick="disable(this);" />'+
      '<input type="text" id="Q'+counter+'choice1" placeholder="Option' + counter1 +' Q'+ counter +'" ">' +
      '<input type="button" value="Add Option" id="Q'+ counter +'">');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
alert(counter);
counter++;
 });

 $("#removeQuestion").click(function () {
if(counter==1){
      alert("No question that can be deleted");
      return false;
   }   

counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

 });

 //$("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

// var msg = '';
//for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
 // msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
//}
//      alert(msg);
 //});
});

function disable(element){
element.checked=false;
}

</script>


</head>
```

here is the html

```
<body>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Q1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' ></br>
    <div id="optionList1">
    <input type='radio' onclick="disable(this);" /> <input type='text' id='Q1choice1' value='' placeholder='option1Q1'>
    <input type='button' value='Add Option' name='1' class="inner" id='Q1'>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Question' id='addQuestion'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Question' id='removeQuestion'>

</body>
</html>
```

I use click function and use alert to ensure the id is exist. the problem is when I create next question and put

```
$("#Q2choice1").click(function()
```

it doesnt alert which mean my id doesnt exist. What is the problem of my jquery?

Comment: If you give the click event within $("#addQuestion").click() then it will work. You have attached the event in ready function and at that time it was not created so the event was not attached to that input.

Comment: @sujataChanda i have tried to use setTimeout function but it doesnt appear anything for id Q2choice1

Comment: Yes it was my fault. It was working for me if you create the input witnin 2 secs. But after that it will not work.

Comment: you shuld use newTextBoxDiv.append().html(//yourcode);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.click()` isn't being applied because `$("#Q2choice1")` doesn't exist yet. Use the event delegation version of `.on()` (http://api.jquery.com/on/) to ensure the listener gets attached.

Replace:

```
$("#Q2choice1").click(function (){
    alert ("dsa");
});
```

with:

```
$('body').on('click', '#Q2choice1', function () {
     alert("DSA");
});
```

By applying the listener to the body element you ensure it gets attached. You then delegate to any element you want whether it exists or not.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hr7nR/

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/x6Dcj/1/

i've changed only one element

```
var counter1 = 1;//mcq
var counter = 2;//question
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Q2choice1").click(function (){
    alert ("dsa");
});

$("#addQuestion").click(function () {

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.append().html('<label>Q'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >' + '</br>' + 
      '<input type="radio" onclick="disable(this);" />'+
      '<input type="text" id="Q'+counter+'choice1" placeholder="Option' + counter1 +' Q'+ counter +'" ">' +
      '<input type="button" value="Add Option" id="Q'+ counter +'">');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
alert(counter);
counter++;
 });

 $("#removeQuestion").click(function () {
if(counter1==1){
      alert("No question that can be deleted");
      return false;
   }   

counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

 });

 //$("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

// var msg = '';
//for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
 // msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
//}
//      alert(msg);
 //});
});

function disable(element){
element.checked=false;
}
```